# Difference between array<int, size> name and int name[size]

Tags: c++, arrays

I found two ways to create an array. What is the difference between them?

1. `array<int, 5> arr = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6};`
2. `int  arr[5] = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6};`

I also found that I can use `arr.size()` in *1*, but I have to use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)` in *2*.

Comment: Also, what is the using of pointers to find the length when you can just use sizeof()?

Comment: Arrays are dumb, `std::array` is smart.  That's the difference.  Also `int x[1000]; std::cout << sizeof(x);` -- Have you actually tried doing this?  Are the results what you expected?

Comment: FYI, since C++11, you can use `std::size(arr);` to get the element count of both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TYPE NAME[SIZE]` has always been the way to declare an array and C++ inherited that from C

OTOH [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a new feature in C++11. It's a struct wrapping the old array inside. It has a member named `size()` to get the number of elements of the internal array. A plain array doesn't have any methods so obviously you can't get the size that way

> what is the using of pointers to find the length when you can just use sizeof()?

`sizeof` returns the size in bytes, not the number of elements. And you don't need to use pointers to get the length. `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` and `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` are 2 common ways to get size, with the latter more prone to error when changing the type of the array

A plain array also [decays to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/995714) so you can't get the size of it inside functions. You must get the size beforehand using `sizeof` and pass the size to the function explicitly. `std::array` has information about size so the size is known inside functions, but you'll need to write a template to deal with different array sizes which results in multiple implementations of the same function because each instantiation of a templated type is a different type. In this case passing a pointer and size of the array is the better solution

Comment: Technically, `arr[0]` is specified as being equivalent to an expression using pointers i.e.  `*(arr+0)`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> array<int, 5> arr = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6}
> ```

This needs to `#include <array>`. You're creating an object (of class `array`) that accepts template arguments `int` and `5`. By using this container, you can have the benefit of the built-in `size()` member function.

> ```
> int arr[5] = {5, 8, 1, 3, 6};
> ```

This is a simple C-style array declaration. This is not an object from any class, neither it needs any header to be declared. You need to make your user-defined `size()` function. Note that you're trying to get the size of a *pointer* to integer – `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` that returns the size of the elements in bytes. You need to use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` instead – so this returns the total *number* of elements.